# Can tun packets be forwarded?

Tags: linux, networking

I experimented with code from https://blog.oddbit.com/post/2023-02-14-whos-got-the-packet/

Here is my setup:

**VM** A (eth1: 10.223.0.2)  ================> **VM** B (eth0: 10.23.56.200)

Reason for making "VM" bold is, the IPs above are not public IPs and I do not know what difference that makes.

I created tun0 and set address as 10.23.56.199.

I enabled forwarding: `sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

Disabled rp_filter: for all

```
for device in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*
do
   echo 0 >${device}/rp_filter
done
```

None of this yielded results.

So, I added the forwarding from tun0 to eth1, just so that I could see if I get tun0 packets on eth1 on **VM A** (same machine).

```
sudo iptables -t filter -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t filter -I FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

I can see packets on tun0 using command `tcpdump  -nn -vv -i tun0 port 10001`
But I do not get any result when I replace `tun0` with `eth1`

Is there a way I can get packets written on `tun0` to `eth1` on same machine and then *VM B* eth1?

I have verified that packets are not being dropped by using `netstat -i`

Thanks in advance!